# Mockito: When any instance invokes method, thenReturn something

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm very new to Mockito and have a class like

```
public class A {
   private B b;
   public B getB() { return b; }
   // ...
}
```

and

```
public class B {
   private C c;
   public C getC() { return c; }
   // ...
}
```

I am writing unit tests using Mockito for class A, and trying to achieve the following behavior, where B is a mock:

```
when(a.getB().getC()).thenReturn(mock(C.class))
when(any(mock(C.class)).doSomething()).thenReturn("somethingElse") // This doesn't work.
```

How can I return "somethingElse" when any mocked instance of C calls doSomething()? I don't want to bind this behavior to any one particular mock(C.class) instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to treat your test subject as a unit, and mock everything else. So since you're testing class `A` you cannot mock `A`s methods.

Here's how you would use Mockito to mock the instance of `B` using annotations:

```
@MockitoSettings
public class ATest {
  @Mock
  private B b;
  @InjectMocks
  private A a;

  @Test
  void testExample() {
    C c = mock(C.class):
    when(b.getC()).thenReturn(c);
    when(c.doSomething()).thenReturn("somethingElse");
    
    // a.getB() == b
  }
}
```

So what is happening here?

The annotation `@Mock` is intializing a mocked object of type `B` and setting the field variable `b` to it.

`@InjectMocks` is collecting all `@Mock` fields and setting the fields in the object. This is your test subject.

Now your `A` instance has a mocked `B` object. And within B you have `C`. Since `B` is a mocked object the method `getC()` doesn't do anthing at all. You have to stub it with some functionality. In the test, I've initialized a local mocked `C` instance to be returned from `getC()`.

So now when `A` object accesses the mocked `B` and get `C` it will get this local variable `c` to use. So you can stub this object with mocked functions.

Comment: This will only return "somethingElse" for this one instance of c. I want a rule that returns "somethingElse" when any object of type C calls doSomething(). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, you cannot do that with `Mockito`. You would have to use the `PowerMock` library.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the ```mock()`` its used for creating new mocks.

Like this

```
when(any(C.class).doSomething()).thenReturn("somethingElse");
```